# To plot 6 different scatter plots in one plot via the ax parameter - not working

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I'm exploring a dataset of world suicides from 1985 to 2016 and try to show the number of suicides by generation - they are divided into six categories in this dataset.

My goal is to create a scatter plot that includes the six generations in one figure. To do that, I created the normalised weights and plotted the data:

- This is the code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/96XZz.png
- This is the output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTwrN.png

It always appears in six different scatter plots. I have no idea why I couldn't put them in one figure, I have googled the way of using the ax parameter but didn't find any helpful guide or solution...

Comment: It would help responders (and you might even solve your own problem) if you made a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We don't have access to your data and it's not even clear what package you are using to produce the plots.

Comment: Hi, @kevinkayaks thank you so much for the comment - will check the link you provided and see if I can rephrase my question. I'm using the matplotlib package to produce the plot.